# Change height of a math command

Tags: brackets

I want to change the effective height of the `\ket{...}` command (from the `braket` package). I *don't* want to change the visual appearance of the ket, I just want change its *effective* height.

Ideally this change would be in both directions, i.e. it would be slightly bigger both above and below.

*Is this possible?*

### The current behavior:

If I do `\left( \ket{x} \right)`, then the parentheses are the exact
same height as the ket, which is not visually pleasing and can be very
confusing when using `\rangle` instead of parentheses.

### The desired outcome:

If I do `\left( \ket{x} \right)`, then the resulting parentheses
should be slightly bigger then the ket (as if the ket were slightly
bigger then it looks). The output should be roughly the same as `\big( \ket{x} \big)` (perhaps a little bigger).
The reason I can't just use `\big` instead of `\left\right` is that the parenthesis might contain other stuff (for which `left\right` is more appropriate) and I don't want to have to edit this in a case-by-case basis.

I feel like it must be possible to make latex think that command is a little taller than it actually is, so that the parentheses will look right automatically.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you *don't* want `\Big` size, but rather `\big`. Typing `$\bigl(\ket{x}\bigr)$` is not heavier than `$\left(\ket{x}\right)$`.

Comment: Actually, I want neither. The problem is that the ket's size varies depending on what's inside. And I want the parenthesis around it to be a little larger then the ket, even when the ket is bigger then `\big` or `\Big`.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't bother; keep in mind that the enlargement is by discrete steps: normal, big, Big, bigg and Bigg, so you can't, in general, have "slightly larger" parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've set on using vphantom for this. Here is the code:

```
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1 \right \rangle \vphantom{\left( #1 \right)^A}\!}    %ket
```

The `^A` superscript guarantees that the vphantom command wll be just a little taller than the actual visual appearance of everything else.